# ¿Qué textos hay que no han sido traducidos?

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones

Hay algunos lugares en los que un texto no ha sido traducido -he encontrado algunos de esos personalmente. Para llamar la atención del equipo desarrollo de Stack Exchange, debemos listar estos lugares, para corregirlos.

Así -¿qué textos hay que no han sido traducidos?

---

Además del contenido en sí, aquí se pueden solicitar también la sustitución de enlaces a material en inglés por traducciones o material equivalente en español.

---

Atención: sólo para textos que **no** fueron traducidos. Si lo que se encuentra es un texto que está en español, ver [Sugerencias de mejora en las traducciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/83/sugerencias-de-mejora-en-las-traducciones).

**IMPORTANTE:** Desde que se marcan las respuestas con [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado) hasta que el cambio es realmente visible puede pasar un tiempo (minutos, horas en el peor caso) dado que tras cambiar los textos hay que esperar a que alguien lance una compilación del código para que los cambios se apliquen.

Answer (score 5):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado) (véase [L10n de “to”, “from”, “with…chosen” y “worth…reputation” en el historial de revisiones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXxKm.png))

En el historial de revisiones, los textos relacionados con las recompensas aparecen en ingles.

Ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/5682/revisions

Evidencia:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Este reporte ya tiene 11 meses. ¿Se le habrá pasado a JuanM?

Comment: @Rubén seguro que lo han visto, al menos Konami. Casi seguro es algo que solo lo puede resolver un developer, por eso no esta resuelto aun.

Comment: Jeje, de que lo hayan visto no tengo duda, me refería a que entre tantos pendientes este se quedó olvidado en "el rincón".

Comment: Sigue pendiente aún.

Comment: ¡Listas ya! Sigamos adelante.

Comment: Eliminé estado-completado y recuperé la pregunta... este no está resuelto todavía (tengo un PR que necesita más amor antes de que pueda ser mergeado)

Comment: Más amor, ese PR lo merece.

Comment: @EmanuelVe ese PR recibe amor sólo cuando no estoy trabajando... encima ahora estoy de viaje... y con otros proyectitos en la vuelta... pobre PR.

Comment: @EmanuelVe apenas fueron 2 años :-) hay que agradecerle a g3rv4 que la luchó en esta

Answer (score 5):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

Desde hace varios días estoy visualizando esta fecha que a mi parecer está en ingles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: creo que en eso estamos fritos hasta las proximas elecciones.. y si tocan en junio.. jul, sep, oct, nov,, feb, mar, may no nos vamos a dar cuenta...

Comment: No tengo forma de corroborarlo, pero esto ya debería estar traducido. Todas las demás cadenas que traduje impactaron bien en la base, y las 12 cadenas de meses eran parte de eso, por lo que asumo que está hecho.

Comment: @Mariano habrá que convocar una elección para probarlo :D

Comment: @fedorqui esperemos al mes que viene para que no diga "*Mar*", como mencionó gbianchi... Tenemos que convocar sin falta para abril

Comment: @Mariano de hecho, un moderador podría crear un evento de prueba y eliminarlo en el momento. Son un par de clicks.

Comment: @fedorqui sólo era un poco de sarcasmo (un CM tiene que ***identificar*** la falta primero)... Pero no creo que valga la pena probarlo: aún si el mes aparece traducido como `mar 25`, sigue sin estar localizado (el mes después del día)... Estaría finalizada está traducción pero estaríamos llamado a otro problema nuevo (que no me parece tan importante ahora). -g3rv4 es el único que podría solucionarlo, y mejor que use su tiempo en otra cosa.

Answer (score 4):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

En [`/review`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review) podemos acceder a las colas de revisión. A la derecha aparece este texto:

> Ayuda a mejorar el sitio
>
> Stack Overflow en español es moderado por [ti](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/).

El enlace dirige a la entrada de blog *A Theory of Moderation*, que Rubén acaba de traducir en [Una teoría de moderación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2227/83) .

Mi propuesta es cambiar el enlace para que apunte a esta publicación en castellano. Además, para que el enlace sea más visible sugiero que todo el texto *es moderado por ti* sea el que actúa como enlace, en lugar de *ti* solamente.

Comment: Listo, lo llevé a otra respuesta para mantenerlos mejor ordenados.

Comment: Relacionado en esta misma pregunta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2335/127 (mismo tipo de enlaces)

Comment: @Mariano no entiendo, estas salen bien en [`/review`](/review) pero las traducciones no aparecen en Transifex: https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/136222262?q=is%20moderated%20by

Comment: SO está continuamente eliminando las traducciones (regenerando nuevos IDs)... Lo que importa es lo que esté en la base de SO... ¿qué llega de todo lo que proponemos? ... es un gran misterio

Answer (score 4):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

Cuando una respuesta entra en la cola de revisión [Publicaciones de baja calidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/), existe una serie de comentarios predefinidos que se pueden añadir al motivo por el que se debería borrar.

Entre ellos, este:

> Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta. En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Mejor es [proveer respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - Desde revisión

Si os fijáis, el último enlace lleva a la pregunta de Meta Stack Exchange [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)  Sin embargo, [observo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1381/83) que esta pregunta de FAQ fue traducida por Emmanuel Ve en [¿Por qué necesito 50 puntos de reputación para comentar? ¿Qué alternativa tengo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/83)

Sugiero pues cambiar el enlace para que apunte a la publicacíon en castellano.

Answer (score 3):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

Cuando ingresas un nuevo comentario, aparece *Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post. Outdated comments may get deleted. Learn more about comments…*. y al final se puede leer *Learn more about formatting…* cosas que deberían ser traducidas.
[image: Error]

Comment: Traducido en [Comments are used to ask for clarification or to…](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/131930226?key=818dc806d16ee7b5059f73ce907e264c) (esperando aprobación); [Learn more about comments](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/131930192?key=8e9e1882cf29c2a8d184422476b4b834) (aprobado); [Learn more about formatting](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/131930190?key=653a8d818f3c12e123dd7e69f7ba98b4) (aprobado)

Comment: y [Comments use mini-Markdown formatting…](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/$/131930161?key=8b4803ddb471e438116d37e5ed945099) (esperando aprobación)

Comment: @Mariano aquí también se perdieron las sugerencias

Comment: @fedorqui creo que podemos asumir que Transifex perdió el 90% del trabajo hecho... Hay que esperar a que g3rv4 arme la versión 2 de la app para ver si podemos salvarnos con eso.

Comment: @Mariano entonces tal vez habría que recuperar las respuestas eliminadas de este hilo, pues puede que haya cosas que ya estaban completadas y ahora ya no.

Comment: @fedorqui puede ser, es un buen punto para estar atento. No obstante lo veo muy poco probable, ya que se eliminaron las que se visualizaban bien. Es decir, las que ya estaban en la base de datos, por lo que no importa si SO borró la cadena de Transifex o no. Si está en la base de datos de SO, se ve bien.

Answer (score 3):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

En el sitio principal y en Meta, al [Formular una pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), cuando se empieza a **agregar etiquetas**, he encontrado esto:

[image: Texto]

### Mi propuesta de traduccion:

> ### Cómo etiquetar
>
> Una etiqueta es una palabra clave que categoriza tu pregunta con otras preguntas similares, Escoje una o mas (hasta 5) etiquetas que ayudaran a quienes responden a encontrar e interpretar tu pregunta.
>
> ► completa la frase: *mi pregunta es acerca de...*
>
> ► usa etiquetas que describan cosas o conceptos que sean *esenciales*, no casuales para tu pregunta
>
> ► prefiere usar las [etiquetas populares](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags)
>
> ► lee las descripciones que aparecen debajo de la etiqueta
>
> Si tu pregunta respecta a un tema del cual no encuentras una etiqueta:
>
> ► combina multiples palabras en una usando guiones (e.g. [cierre-de-preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cierre-de-preguntas)), hasta un maximo de 25 caracteres
>
> ► [crear una etiqueta es un privilegio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags); si aun no puedes crear la etiqueta que necesitas, entonces publica una pregunta sin la etiqueta, para [solicitar a la comunidad su creacion](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Eso  tambien pasa en el sitio principal

Comment: La oración [A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your…](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/$/134814727?key=1f9feb8c560a84e861201618865a5995) está esperando aprobación... el resto no está en Transifex. Probablemente sea un Site Config, por lo que dependemos de que JuanM lo haga.

Comment: Todo traducido finalmente

Answer (score 3):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

En la sección *Mini Perfil*, dentro de *Edición y configuración del perfil* hay un texto sin traducir:

> If you participate on multiple [Stack
>   Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) sites, you can also show off
>   your combined profiles:

Sugerencia:
Si participas en múltiples sitios de [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/), también puedes mostrar tus perfiles combinados:

[image: Sección Mini Perfil]

---

[estado-postergado](/questions/tagged/estado-postergado)

De ser posible, cambiar también el texto que está dentro de la imagen:

> You do not have any linked
>   accounts with 200+ rep

Sugerencia:
`No tiene ninguna cuenta vinculada con 200+ rep.`

Answer (score 2):

[estado-por-diseño](/questions/tagged/estado-por-dise%c3%b1o)

No sé si cuenta como parte del sitio o es independiente y pertenece directamente a la red Stackexchange. Sin embargo, en el chat hay varios textos sin traducir:

- Cuando despliegas la información en un comentario que se ha marcado como favorito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Dónde indica que hay más salas de chat y las opciones encima de los últimos usuarios conectados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Aquí la cosa está complicada, el chat tiene su propia base de código y no incorpora ningún mecanismo para traducciones :-(

Comment: @Konamiman Eso me había imaginado ya que se pueden ver todas las salas de chat a la vez. Una pena :(. Por cierto, muchas gracias por corregir el otro mensaje :)

Answer (score 2):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado) (véase [L10n de “to”, “from”, “with…chosen” y “worth…reputation” en el historial de revisiones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/2085/revisions))

- Cuando se migra una pregunta de Meta al sitio principal se lee algo así como ([*ejemplo*](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/2085/revisions)):

  > Publicación migrada **to** es.stackoverflow.com por X

  Este *to* está en inglés y debería ser *migrada **a***.
- Al igual que con el destino de la migración ([*ejemplo*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/74583/revisions)):

  > Publicación migrada aquí **from** es.meta.stackoverflow.com

  Este *from* está en inglés y debería ser ***de***

---

<strike>Luego se ve también</strike>

> Publicación bloqueada por **Community**♦

Que podría cambiarse por Comunidad como se ha hecho en otros lugares.

Véase un [ejemplo reciente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/2088/revisions).

Comment: Dicho y hecho :-) Al modificar el nombre del usuario ([Traducir el perfil de meta del usuario Comunidad ♦](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2051/127)), ahora se ve "[Publicación bloqueada por Comunidad ♦](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/2088/revisions)"... Chat relacionado: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38565288#38565288

Comment: @Mariano qué bien, gracias por perseguir el tema. En cuanto a lo de _publicación migrada aquí **from**_, veo que sugieres _migrada aquí **de**_, pero ¿no te suena mejor _migrada aquí **desde**_?

Comment: Me suena algo más natural "de", porque el enlace apunta al origen (stub/talón/colilla/resabio) de migración (no al sitio en general), pero no tendría problema con "desde"... En cuyo caso, habría que modificarlo también en otros lados donde se propuso "de", y no recuerdo si alguno no fue ya implementado.

Comment: Genial, gracias @Mariano. No tengo claro quién lo marca ahora como [meta-tag:estado-completado]. ¿Es g3rv4 después de mirar el spreadsheet, somos nosotros revisando si está ya en la web o hay alguna manera nueva?

Comment: Ni idea... ¿En algún momento se habló cuáles serían los pasos para traducir? Creo que en la charla dijeron que iban a publicar en el Centro de Ayuda y en Meta... Yo no estoy participando activamente, sólo marqué algunos términos que me tenían muy cansado de verlos en inglés en la web y revisé el estado de esta publicación

Comment: @Mariano yo entendí que se iba a publicar en breve la metodología a seguir.

Answer (score 2):

[estado-por-diseño](/questions/tagged/estado-por-dise%c3%b1o)

Cuando el usuario `Comunidad` hace alguna modificación en una pregunta, la descripción aparece en inglés.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Este fue un cambio semi-manual que programaron los desarrolladores de [se] al hilo de [HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/209901) para modificar todo http a https. Por tanto, es un texto que introdujeron manualmente, no un bug de traducción.

Comment: @fedorqui Gracias por la aclaración :). Yo de todas maneras lo puse porque no sabía como detectar si un texto se puede traducir o no...

Answer (score 2):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

Cuando vas a eliminar una pregunta que contiene una respuesta con votos positivos o más de una respuesta, te dice:

> You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the [help center](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)

Esto podría traducirse a algo así como:

> No puedes eliminar esta pregunta, pues hay gente que ha invertido tiempo  y esfuerzos contestándola. Para más información, visita el [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)

Comment: La traduje parecida cuando leí [esta otra publicación duplicada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2678/127) como "*No puedes eliminar esta pregunta, ya que otros usuarios han invertido tiempo y esfuerzo en responderla. Para obtener más información, consulta el $linkStart$Centro de Ayuda$linkEnd$.*" en [transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/132687529?key=689ef75f6d47e75b1bb54bc8fa717fb4)

Comment: @Mariano está bien, ambas mantienen la idea :) Cuando g3rv4 la acepte le ponemos la etiqueta de [meta-tag:estado-completado].

Comment: Así se ve ahora: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBWIo.png

Answer (score 2):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

He encontrado dos palabras que estan en ingles en la versión para **móviles**, en la parte de **usuarios** donde se puede editar el **[correo electrónico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current).**

Y el otro seria el apartado donde dice **YOUR COMMITES**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Propuse [Configuración de Mail](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/$/113295235?key=9070b35e0d637593ce9e85705889aea2) (en vez de "correo electrónico" para mantener un texto corto en la web mobile)... y [Tus Comunidades](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/$/113295226?key=84d7e69c0304c3451c5a1d508bc976c5) ... Esperando que lo aprueben

Comment: @Mariano esta bien muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

Si accedes a la web sin tener una sesión abierta, una pregunta protegida ([ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/36)) se indica con un texto no traducido:

> Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality or spam answers that had to be removed, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site (the association bonus does not count).
>
> Would you like to answer one of these unanswered questions instead?

Comment: El texto se encuentra en Transifex pero aún no está traducido -> [Thank you for your interest in this question…](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/132434128?key=0a2b7d92f5a9c9dede3336a9511776c3)

Comment: @Rubén sí, lo vi. Es curioso porque sugiere uno muy similar. ¿Será otro caso de pequeño cambio en el texto original que hace que se pierda la traducción?

Comment: El texto de las dos cadenas que ahora se muestra es idéntico, lo que cambia son las propiedades, una de la variantes tiene "variant:one" y la otra "variant:other" :)

Comment: @Rubén ah vale, veo que la diferencia con los textos sugeridos (los que salen en la columna de la derecha, pestaña _Suggestions_) es que ahora (bueno, [desde 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280765/209901)) incluye el texto _the association bonus does not count_. Entiendo pues que la ausencia de esta traducción viene de lejos.

Comment: Sugerí la traducción en [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/132434128?key=0a2b7d92f5a9c9dede3336a9511776c3)... Esperando que revisen.

Comment: Reportado en [Falta revisar la traducción del texto que acompaña a las publicaciones protegidas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3278/83)

Answer (score 1):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

Cuando llegas a **10 ediciones** pendientes de aprobar ya no puedes hacer otra edición más aparece este error:

> You have too many pending edits. Further edits cannot be submitted until prior edits have been approved.

Dejo la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El texto en transifex, ya tiene traducción pero aún no se ha revisado -> [You have too many pending edits. Further edits…](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/92541633?key=92c79533a66a1f9c1be267432d8e93b6)

Comment: Gracias @Rubén esperaremos que los revisen

Answer (score 1):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

Cuando tienes manazas y te equivocas repetidamente con la contraseña (es decir, si te llamas fedorqui), te sale la pantallita:

> Verificación humana
>
> **Are you a human being?** We apologize for the confusion, but we can't quite tell if you're a person or a script. Please don't take this personally. Bots and scripts can be remarkably lifelike these days!
>
> Verifica la casilla de CAPTCHA, y te dejaremos pasar.

Como se ve, el primer párrafo no está traducido.

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [`**¿Eres un ser humano?** Pedimos disculpas por la confusión, pero no podemos distinguir _con certeza_ si eres una persona o un script. No lo tomes como algo personal. Los scripts y los bots pueden ser bastante parecidos a los seres vivos actualmente.`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/133641640?key=882b4d6b5c9c7b0d8fa0c8523d9947e6) (queda ahí para que cualquiera modifique o que se apruebe)

Answer (score 1):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

Cuando editas algo pero luego lo deshaces, sale este mensaje:

> [Edit removed during grace period]

Lo que en román paladino se podría escribir como:

> [Edición eliminada durante el período de gracia]

([ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/43451/revisions))

Comment: Traduje recién en [\[Edit removed during grace period\]](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/135129074?key=0b0dee08acad5d7c8cbde8ea2de60033)... esperando revisión

Answer (score -1):

Luego de más de un año en beta pública se ha vuelto muy inpráctico colaborar en este tema ([spotting](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotting) de traducciones faltantes) de esta forma (agregar respuestas a un único hilo)

1. Ya hay dos páginas de respuestas
2. El botón de Publicar Respuesta se encuentra en la parte inferior de la página
3. Se muestra un diálogo advirtiendo que ya hay mas de 30 respuestas

[image]

Propuesta:

Cerrar este hilo y agregar a la pregunta que las nuevos spottings debe de reportarse como nuevas preguntas con las etiquetas [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) y [traducciones](/questions/tagged/traducciones)

Comment: Puede ser, pero particularmente a mí me resulta muy práctico tener todo en 1 solo lugar. La cuestión es que si encuentro una frase que no fue traducida, lo primero que hago es buscar si no fue reportada previamente, y buscarlo en diferentes publicaciones, por más que estén bien etiquetadas, puede ser tedioso... Y por la insistencia de Konamiman, también parece que le resulta más práctico así... Recomiendo no ordenar esta publicación por votos sino [por actividad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/40/qu%c3%a9-textos-hay-que-no-han-sido-traducidos?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: dado que ya lo consultaste en [¿Qué hacemos con los hilos de lista de cosas sobre traducciones?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3133/83) y ya se eliminaron las solucionadas, supongo que esta respuesta ya no es necesaria

Comment: [wipe them out. all of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39JvV.gif)