# Cómo formular preguntas en el Beta Privado o ¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?

Tags: soporte, traducciones, centro-de-ayuda

**Actualización:**

Debido a que el sitio ya no se encuentra en Beta he propuesta el cierre de la pregunta.

*Sería muy sencillo la eliminación, trato de que exista indicios que al menos haya aportado al sitio.*

---

**13/03/2017:**

Cuando accedes al [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) lo primero que te encuentras en la sección **Preguntar** es [Cómo formular preguntas en el Beta Privado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta). Pero si accede a la opción [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), al lado derecho tendrás la opción [cómo pedir ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

**Cómo formular preguntas en el Beta Privado**, solo indica algo genérico del cómo deberían ser las preguntas.

En cambio, **¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta? (cómo pedir ayuda)**, contiene lo anterior con datos que son fundamentales a la hora de formular una pregunta.

¿Se debería actualizar la información del Centro de Ayuda o se debe mantener?

---

Asimismo, en la opción **ver más** de las secciones [**Respondiendo**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answering) y [**Nuestro modelo**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange) nos encontraremos con [Why are answers no longer being accepted from my account?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) y [What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts) los cuales tienen contenido en inglés.

El **Centro de Ayuda**, debería informar en forma clara y con contenido en Español, debido a que siempre solicitamos de forma directa o indirecta visitarlo.

Comment: No deben usarse dos etiquetas obligatorias juntas, si resultara "tentador" hacerlo, es posible que la pregunta fuera demasiado amplia. Discusión es para solicitar opiniones, soporte es para solicitar orientación directa (cómo se hace o funciona algo) o ayuda para la solución de problemas.

Comment: Esta pregunta debería ser cerrada pues el sitio ya se graduó y no tiene sentido que esté siendo relanzada por "Community".

Comment: @Rubén como toda pregunta tiene la opción de ser cerrada a votación, favor de proponer el cierre e indicar porqué no está relacionada.

Comment: @Davlio: Mi estimado Davilo, es lo que hice, puse un comentario y realicé un reporte. ¿ te referías a esto, a otra cosa o esperas "lujo de detalle"?

Comment: Actualmente el sitio no se encuentra en Beta

Comment: @Rubén: Bueno, los reportes necesitan intervención de un moderador, pero si se propone un cierre ya sería a votación y sería más rápido cerrar la pregunta. Eso es lo que hice :). PD. "LUJO DE DETALLE", es sarcástico de tu parte...

Comment: @Davlio: No era mi intención sonar sarcástico, lamento que lo tomes así. Lo mencioné porque no entiendo a qué se debe tu comentario y  a que las explicaciones sobre como funciona el cierre de preguntas innecesarias.

Comment: Yo no dije "pregunta innecesaria".

Comment: Lo que dije es que las explicaciones eran innecesarias, no las preguntas. En momentos así me acuerdo de la semántica para vocabularios y reglas de negocio de la OMG, jeje, y también me siento tentado a sentirme culpable por haber sido escueto :)

Comment: Sobre los indicios que mencionas en la actualización, la pregunta al momento tiene 62 vistas, una puntuación de 3, tiene una respuesta con una puntuación de 1. Podría tener más indicios, sin embargo, al menos con estos podemos decir que no ha pasado desapercibida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar, muy buenas observaciones (spottings)

Cabe mencionar que actualmente nos encontramos en Beta Público, por lo que el artículo de Beta Privado no debería ser lo primero que se muestre en el Centro de Ayuda.

El artículo sobre cómo formular preguntas en Beta Privado tiene su razón de ser de estar como está. Por ahora no tiene *sentido de urgencia* actualizarlo pues no se lanzarán nuevos sitios en español en el corto plazo (pendiente agregar referencias), pero definitivamente es algo que tiene que hacerse previo a un nuevo lanzamiento de beta privado.

En cuanto a las traducciones, por favor revisa las etiquetas [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) en combinación con [traducciones](/questions/tagged/traducciones) -> https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug+traducciones

Ejemplo:

[¿Qué textos hay que no han sido traducidos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/40/qu%C3%A9-textos-hay-que-no-han-sido-traducidos/1432#1432)

Anexos

Captura 1
[image: Página de inicio de Centro de Ayuda de SOes]

Captura 2
[image: Formular una pregunta en SOes]