# Eliminar página "Cómo formular preguntas en el Beta Privado "

Tags: discusión, centro-de-ayuda

En la sección *Preguntar* de la ayuda hay una página que habla sobre como preguntar en el Beta Privado cuando ya hace mucho que no estamos en beta: [Cómo formular preguntas en el Beta Privado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta)

Hay una pregunta que ya propuso eliminar esa página cuando el sitio cambió de beta privado a público: [Cómo formular preguntas en el Beta Privado o ¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1521/7176). Esa pregunta esta bloqueada así que no se puede continuar ahí la discusión.

Veo que en SO en inglés también se mantiene esa página de la ayuda y tampoco entiendo por qué, de hecho parece que también se ha propuesto eliminarla pero ahí ha quedado la cosa: [Remove “How to Ask Questions in Private Beta” from the Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342473/4994625)

¿Hay algún impedimento técnico para borrarla? Si no es así yo creo que deberíamos eliminarla porque solo sirve para confundir.

Comment: Preguntemosle al CM Nicolas.. tal vez haya algun otro motivo por lo cual se mantiene...

Comment: ¿Cuál es el inconveniente de tener las páginas en cuestión? ¿Existen casos reales de dichos inconvenientes?

Comment: Básicamente que no aporta nada, ya hay en la ayuda una página sobre cómo preguntar. Y habla del sitio como si fuese todavía beta. Aparte de eso no tiene mayor importancia pero si no sirve de nada mejor borrarla, eso pienso yo.

Comment: Quizá sea suficiente con editarla y quitar eso de "Bienvenido a la beta privada de..." o poner una nota aclarando que el sitio no está en beta.

Comment: Quizá no aporta pero no veo que estorbe en verdad. En lo personal si eso va a costar tiempo de un desarrollador yo preferiría que se invirtiera en una de tantas cosas por mejorar antes que en eso. Independientemente de eso, veo bien que hayas traído el tema a la discusión.

Comment: También comentado en Meta.SE --> [“How to Ask Questions in Private Beta” is listed in every site’s help centre](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290401/209901)

Comment: A todo esto, no entiendo por qué bloqueó esa otra pregunta. Si tuviera reputación suficiente revisaría la lista de últimas preguntas bloqueadas https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/protected-questions

Answer (score 5):

Version en español:

Es una pregunta integral que afecta a todos los sitios de Stack Exchange. Creo que el mejor lugar para hacer esta pregunta es en MSE. No tengo todos los detalles exactos de por qué funciona de esta manera y no de otra, asi que déjenme asumir. Mi versión de porque no podemos borrarla tiene dos por qué:

1. Así es como funciona el sistema del centro de ayuda. Originalmente agregamos un artículo sobre MSE. Si agregamos un artículo que se agrega a todos los sitios dentro de un idioma, en un sitio en particular podemos anular el contenido del artículo, pero no podemos eliminar u ocultar el artículo. Déjenme enfatizar:

   - Podemos agregar un nuevo artículo para un sitio que ninguno de los otros sitios tendrá.
   - Podemos anular un artículo existente.
   - Pero no podemos eliminar uno que ya existía en MSE.

   Eso significa que solo hay una forma de eliminarlo: para todos los sitios a la vez. Ninguno de los otros sitios lo tendrá, incluidos los que están en beta privada.
2. Todos los sitios de Stack Exchange se crean a través del Área 51 por usuarios existentes. Significa que los usuarios de, por ejemplo, SOen necesitan saber acerca de las versiones beta privadas y públicas y cómo hacer preguntas durante esas etapas, incluso antes del lanzamiento de un nuevo sitio.

---

A lot of thanks to [@gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi) for the translation!

Original from Nicolas:

It's a comprehensive question that affects all Stack Exchange sites. I think the best place for it on MSE. I do not all exact details why it goes this way but not the others, thought let me assume. My version has two why we can not delete it:

1. This is how the help center system works. Originally we add an article on MSE. If we add an article it gets added for all sites within a language, then on a particular site we can override the content of the article but cannot delete or hide the article. Let me emphasise:

   - We can add a new article for a site that none of the other sites will have.
   - We can override an existed article
   - But we cannot delete one that already existed on MSE.

   That means that there is only one way to delete it — for all sites at once. None of other sites will have it, including ones that in private beta.
2. All Stack Exchange sites are created through Area 51 by existing users. It means users of, for example, SOen need to know about the private and public betas and how to ask questions during that stages even before the launch of a new site.

Comment: Still, it doesn't make much sense having such page after leaving the private Beta phase. I see it was also discussed in Meta.SE --> [“How to Ask Questions in Private Beta” is listed in every site’s help centre](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290401/209901)