# Traducir el perfil de meta del usuario Comunidad ♦

Tags: característica-nueva, usuario-comunidad

Veo que el usuario [Comunidad ♦](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidad?tab=profile) tiene su perfil en español. Pero si toco en su perfil usuario de meta, sale en inglés, y queda [Community♦](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile).

Me gustaría que quede igual que en su perfil del sitio principal, y que quede vinculada la información, en caso de que haya cambios en alguno de los dos.

Comment: Sería divertido que de aquí un tiempo el propio usuario Comunidad relanzara esta pregunta al grito de _¡eeeey, quiero esto!_ :)

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que un moderador puede modificar el nombre de un usuario, y que esta propuesta tiene todos votos positivos, ¿no deberías modificarlo?

Comment: @Mariano No puedo cambiarlo. Puedo con los demás usuarios, pero con ese no.

Comment: @ArtEze oka, gracias por la info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya está hecha la traducción. Gracias Juan M.