# Traduccion en seccion de reporte de un comentario

Tags: bug, traducciones

Intente reportar un comentario, aunque no interesa el contenido del mensaje (obviare ese detalle), me encontré con las opciones de mensajes para reportarlo  en ingles:

Reporto este comentario como

```
  **irrespetuoso o abusivo** This comment violates our "Be Nice" policy.  
 **no longer needed** This comment is obsolete, chatty, or otherwise unnecessary.   
**se necesita la intervención de un moderador** Un problema que no está en la lista anterior y que requiere de la intervención de un moderador. ¡Sé específico y detallado!
```

Como traducirlos?

Comment: @Luiggi: La [meta-tag:traducciones-de-contenido] es para traducciones de preguntas y respuestas, pero en este caso se trata de una traducción de elementos de la interfaz de SOes por lo que debería usarse [meta-tag:traducciones].

Comment: Ya se había reportado antes en el hilo adecuado: [¿Qué textos hay que no han sido traducidos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/40/qu%C3%A9-textos-hay-que-no-han-sido-traducidos/2523#2523)

Comment: @Flxtr : Al buscar `no longer needed` este hilo es el único resultado. ¿En qué parte del hilo referido ya se había reportado esto?

Comment: Me refería a existe una pregunta específica donde deben ir las traducciones pendientes o los textos que no han sido traducidos, justo la que pongo en el link. De igual forma no lo encontrarás como texto ya que existe como imagen en el [reporte que se realizó](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2523/16841) ;)

Answer (score 0):

No hay manera de nosotros, los usuarios, hacer esta traducción.

Lo que debemos hacer en estos casos, es crear un *post* aquí en el **meta** así como lo hiciste, y etiquetar con la etiqueta [**`bug`**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) para que un Gerente de Comunidad vea y tome la debida acción en relación a eso.

Siempre que encuentres *bugs*, páginas que faltan, errores de traducción/escritura en la plataforma, etc, esta es la forma como debes proseguir.

Comment: Como se menciona en la [otra respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2647/65), existe un hilo para hacer los reportes de cosas que están pendientes de traducir que es el que se ha venido usando desde la beta privada.

Answer (score 0):

Existe una [publicacion en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/40/qu%C3%A9-textos-hay-que-no-han-sido-traducidos), en el cual se estan dejando los textos que no han sido traducidos aun en el sitio

Alli puedes encontrar en las respuestas los textos que faltan por traducir en el sitio, si ves que tu caso no ha sido aun reportado, puedes dejarlo alli como respuesta e incluso sugerir una traduccion y en este caso [Konamiman♦](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23/konamiman) se encargara se marcarlos como [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado) cuando la traduccion ya haya sido realizada.

Comment: La publicación referida no es una "publicación de Mariano". El OP es ArtOfCode, pero se muestra Mariano porque es el que ha agregado el mayor número de caracteres. En mi opinión es mejor dejar el enlace y que el sistema agregue el título de la publicación.

Comment: Por cierto, el prefijo para las etiquetas en meta es `meta-tag` en lugar de `tag` :)

Comment: @Rubén Muchas gracias por la correccion, no sabia que se escribian meta-tag