# L10n de "to", "from", "with...chosen" y "worth...reputation" en el historial de revisiones

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-completado, traducciones, agregar-a-transifex

En el **historial de revisiones** siguen en inglés `to <url>` y `from <url>` que aparecen tanto con **migraciones** como con **combinaciones** (*merge*).

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Así como también `with <autor>'s answer chosen` y `worth <rep> reputation` de las **recompesas**.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Ejemplos:

1. (combinada) `to`: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/52238/revisions
2. (combinada) `from`: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/51904/revisions
3. (migrada) `to`: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/2085/revisions
4. (migrada) `from`: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/74583/revisions
5. (recompensa) `worth` y `with`: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/5682/revisions

> Reportado previamente en:
>
> - (combinadas): [¿Qué textos hay que no han sido traducidos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1594/127) (yo)
> - (migradas): [¿Qué textos hay que no han sido traducidos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2090/127) (fedorqui)
> - (recompensas): https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/512/127 (Emanuel Ve)

Buscando `to` en Transifex (tarea difícil para *estas* cadenas) encontré los candidatos: [a *$url$*](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/$/133641517?key=8a4d2a8bea0dd4f78b8a0e548a539f2a), [para](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/$/40278570?key=01b6e20344b68835c5ed1ddedf20d531) y [a](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/$/132423629?key=2177f4fdd144e4a6fe0e71858190672c), pero no parecerían ser el caso.

Como están en inglés en SOpt ([ejemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/15969/revisions)) y en ru.so ([ejemplo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/318327/revisions)) -ja.so no combinó ninguna hasta ahora-, me da la pauta de que probablemente no están localizadas.

¿Se les podrá agregar el `_m()`?
-Y un *refersTo* no vendría mal en este caso complicado de encontrar :-)

Comment: PR para localizar esto enviado... ahora a esperar...

Comment: tuve respuesta! y me pidieron varios cambios que acabo de mandar... ojalá que salga esta semana

Comment: @g3rv4 buenísimo. Dan ganas de saber si finalmente van con regex o si se aburren y van con una solución "sana".

Comment: sana? jajajajajajaja pero jajajajajajaja

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Después de muchas idas, vueltas, viajes, dolor, PRs tirados para atrás, refactors... ESTO QUEDÓ PRONTO!!!