# Falta revisar "Comments are used to ask for clarification..."

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducida-falta-revisar

Ya está traducida la cadena siguiente en Transifex pero falta revisar

> Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post. Outdated comments may get deleted.

Liga a Transifex [Comments are used to ask for clarification or to…](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/131930226?key=818dc806d16ee7b5059f73ce907e264c)

NOTA: Ya había sido reportado como texto que no ha sido traducido: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2519/65