# "Appended answer X as supplemental" no aparece en Transifex

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones, agregar-a-transifex

Cuando un usuario publica una respuesta que bien podría ser una edición de su pregunta, el sistema escribe:

> appended answer X as supplemental

Donde X es el identificador de la publicación ([ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/141484/revisions)).

Esto podría traducirse algo verbosamente como:

> añadida la respuesta X como información suplementaria

Tal y como amablemente [indica Mariano](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/40/qu%C3%A9-textos-hay-que-no-han-sido-traducidos/3225?noredirect=1#comment11455_3227), esta cadena no está en Transifex.

Comment: Agregado al PR... si no tengo noticias hoy, le hago ping a un core dev para que lo mire

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, @g3rv4! Entiendo que cuando esté lo marcarás como [meta-tag:estado-completado] y entonces deberé publicar en [¿Qué textos hay que no han sido traducidos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/40/83) para que se añada la traducción.

Comment: lo voy a marcar como [meta-tag:estado-completado] una vez que haya sido aprobado el PR. En el build siguiente, la cadena aparece en transifex y ahí ya seguimos el proceso normal (lo podés traducir vos y un reviewer lo aprueba)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finalmente... quedó mi PR mergeado! esta cadena se puede [encontrar en Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/137905572?key=f648ae606808c53ddc6495c412d2f2fb). En el caso de que alguien la traduzca, por favor pasen [por el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72224/hablemos-sobre-las-traducciones) así coordinamos la revisión y pull.

Si no hacemos esto, se puede perder la traducción.

Comment: Volvió a perderse, pero gracias a https://traducir.win vuelve a estar ya definitivamente traducida. ¡Gracias!