# Falta revisar la traducción del texto que acompaña a las publicaciones protegidas

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducida-falta-revisar

Como se comentó en [esta respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3163/83):

> Si accedes a la web sin tener una sesión abierta, una pregunta
>   protegida ([ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/36)) se indica con un texto no traducido:
>
> > Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality or spam answers that had to be removed, posting
> >     an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site (the association
> >     bonus does not count).
> >
> > Would you like to answer one of these unanswered questions instead?

Mariano añadió una [sugerencia de traducción](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/132434128?key=0a2b7d92f5a9c9dede3336a9511776c3).